# Highcharts: displaying datetime like categories

Tags: datetime, highcharts, format, categories, label

I'm trying to achieve something like this: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8E45.png).
I want to display labels for xAxis like in categories: in Month day-day format. Is it possible to achieve it with 'datetime' type?
This is my xAxis configuration:

```
{
    "type" : "datetime",
    "crosshair" : false,
    "visible" : true,
    "labels" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "padding" : 10
    },
    "minTickInterval" : 86400000,
    "tickLength" : 10,
    "min" : 1507759200000,
    "max" : 1523311199999
}
```

Comment: I don't think that possible `xAxis.tickmarkPlacement` works only with category [API link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickmarkPlacement)

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting `xAxis.labels.x` offset when `xAxis.showLastLabel` is disabled:

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {

  chart: {
    width: 700
  },

  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
      x: 150
    },
    showLastLabel: false
  },

  series: [{
    data: [
      [Date.UTC(2018, 0), 1],
      [Date.UTC(2018, 1), 2],
      [Date.UTC(2018, 2), 2]
    ]
  }]
});
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0bk79bpz/

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.x
- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.showLastLabel